# Can EM Waves from a specific planetary alignment create an earthquake on earth?

Tags: electromagnetism

In the 1950s John H Nelson who worked for the RCA had to do research about short wave radio signal interference's and Blackouts. RCA wanted a prediction model if possible. Nelson found out that those interference's and blackouts were caused by specific planetary positions. NASA adopted his research but called the alignment's gravity vectors. Can EM Waves from a specific planetary alignment create an earthquake on earth ?

Comment: Looking at Nelson's actual research, it's likely that this was basically a coincidence; the variables happened to look correlated, but no causal relationship was proven to exist. Also, what do blackouts have to do with earthquakes?

Comment: Under mainstream physics, nope. Light _is_ an electromagnetic wave. If you need a telescope to tell a planetary alignment is even happening, it's safe to say the electromagnetic radiation associated with such an event is pretty weak.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to access the original research published by John H. Nelson, as it was published far before digitization was a thing. As such, I'll be using this ham radio forum's synopsis as a reference: http://www.eham.net/articles/8828

In general, there are lots of weird correlations one can find if you compare the right datasets. Here's one of my favorites:

[image]

Here's another one:

[image]

These types of *spurious correlations* are found in lots of places, and illustrate the idea that *correlation is not causation*. Just because two variables happen to be somewhat synchronized does not mean that one affects the other. This seems to be what's going on in Nelson's work.

There are several factors lending skepticism to any causative relationship here:

- Nelson's original work included only data from 1950 and 1951. Since both blackouts and planetary alignments are relatively infrequent events, the number of data points in his analysis was likely very small. And the smaller the dataset, the easier it is to get spurious correlations.
- There's some ambiguity in both what you call a planetary alignment and what you call a blackout. Given his research objective under RCA, he likely chose the definition of planetary alignment that gave the best correlation with the definition of blackouts. He ended up choosing his definition such that a "planetary alignment" happened whenever two planets were separated by 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees in heliocentric coordinates; one presumes that had he chosen a different definition, the correlation would disappear.

Comment: Didn't you know? Spiders REALLY loathe long words.